# Unexpected token < error using Angular2 while I try to add directive

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I follow the 5min tour on angular.io;

This is my app.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Banner} from '../components/banner/banner';    

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    styles: [`
    .title {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .container {
      height : 100%;
      overflow : hidden;
    }
  `],
    template: `
    <div class="container">
        <header>
          <banner></banner>
        </header>
    </div>
    `,
    directives: [Banner]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This is my banner.ts,

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'banner',
    template: `
    <h1>Test</h1>
    `
})

export class Banner {

}
```

My file structure looks like this:

```
app
  app.ts
  bootstrap.ts
components
  banner
     banner.ts
index.html
```

In my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Set the base href -->
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>

    <title>Router Sample</title>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- Add the router library -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'},
                  format: 'register'}
      });
      System.import('app/bootstrap')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app>loading...</app>
  </body>

</html>
```

I see an error in my console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  Evaluating
>   http://localhost:3000/components/banner/banner    Error loading
>   http://localhost:3000/app/bootstrap.ts

I don't understand, I follow the instruction on angular.io and try to do what they did, but I get an error.

All I know now is when I try to use the directives, it will give me an error, no matter it's pre-built directives, or the one I built my self.

I also tried to add the `import {Directive} from 'angular2/angular2';`

**I really have no idea on this, please give me some advise before downvote.**

Comment: I think it's a missing import. There are lots of similar questions.

Comment: I follow the angular.io and on their live example, they didn't import other stuff.

Comment: What if you try importing Banner like this `import {Banner} from 'app/components/banner/banner';`?

Comment: No, it gives 404 error, since components and app are the same level folder,

Comment: Try this `packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}, format: 'register', 'components', {defaultExtension: 'ts', format: 'register'}`. Give it a try and let us know if it works. You can alternatively add `.js` to your import line too.

Comment: Why are you including typescript at runtime?  Typescript only used during development.  Would suggest you actually follow the 5 min tutorial more closely as it uses npm to pull the required packages, and includes them locally.  Walk before trying to run...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here is with your System.config

Change your System config as follows:

```
System.config({
    transpiler: 'typescript',
    typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
    packages: {
       'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'},
       'components': {defaultExtension: 'ts'},
        format: 'register'
    }
  });
```

As you can see, I am adding a new package. Since your components folder is outside of 'app' package, it is not getting loaded correctly. (You can load it by expressively adding the extension in your import statement, though it is not the correct thing to do)

Another solution will be to move your components folder inside your app folder, and then also it will work, because you will just have one package called 'app'.

I am also new to this and still learning about it. If anyone has anything to add please do.